# Open ground in dimmer cord. What could be wrong?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, cord-and-plug

I purchased a `SUNTHIN 240W Outdoor Dimmer for String Lights` about a year and a half ago. It has worked perfectly up until about a week ago. We had a large storm which pulled the lights off the hook on the house. In troubleshooting today I've found:

- The lights still work but the aforementioned dimmer does not. It is driven from a still functioning remote control with a working battery.
- I figured the fuse in the plug must have blown. I looked at the fuse and it seems fine.
- I replaced the fuse with one that looked identical from a spare I found
- I plugged in a tester and tried the remote and it reports `open ground`
- I plugged the tester into the receptacle in the wall and it's `correct`

I don't want to replace the $30 dimmer if I don't have to. I'm using it outside in a protected box encasing a GFCI receptacle. A couple follow on questions:

- Is it fixable?
- Can I use it as is?

Thanks

Comment: Fuses should be tested to make sure, have had perfect looking fuses that were blown,only found by testing.  Open ground usually means a ground wire broken/missing.  Ground is for your safety, not for circuit to work.  Wires pulled probably means at least one wire was broken.  Find broken wire and repair or replace.

Comment: @crip659, the dimmer cord was anchored separately from the lights and didn't receive any of that damage. It's possibly water damage from the storm, despite the device having endured many such storms over its use. It's also possible it always would have tested `open ground`. IDK, I never tested it before. I don't see any broken wires inside the controller case.

Answer (score 3):

### You are being unrealistic expecting performance, longevity and safety from cheap junk like this

[image]

Not UL listed. These marks are universally faked, almost as a joke, by these foreign sellers. The authorities responsible for enforcing the marks do nothing about it.  The EU government doesn't want to explain a budget line item for enforcing their mark's use inside China. Nor does the FCC.  (whereas UL, a privately managed public charity, has the freedom to do so).

[image]

Third-party seller.  Most listings on Amazon are actually Amazon Marketplace, a peer-peer trading system similar to eBay. Amazon lets these sellers coat-tail onto their fulfillment system, hence the Prime.

##### *And, I don't think I'm telling you anything you don't already know*.

This type of annoying failure is simply par for the course with these cheap things. Paper-thin safety ground wires are often seen in BigClive teardowns, Youtube has plenty of them.

Be glad it didn't burn your house down or kill somebody... and move on.  If you are sick of junk and want better, get UL-listed gear from a retail home store that answers to the government.

Trying to "fix" them will waste your time [and annoy the pig](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/07/10/sing-pig/).  (believe me, I've tried).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the information, but get off your high horse. I'm hardly the first U.S. based Amazon customer to have bought something made in China. It would be nice if you could filter products by UL listing, but certainly just because a product hasn't been tested doesn't mean it's unsafe. This product was for outdoor use, and I'm not sure what all the legality ranting was for. See this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10639/is-ul-approval-required-on-all-items-sold-in-the-usa#answer-10640

Comment: OK, I've toned it down. That link is a lie.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but thanks for adjusting the answer. I'm guessing the product works exactly as before with the new fuse. I'll certainly seek out more rigorously tested products in the future, but can you clarify anything about the link being a lie. Seems a bit heavy handed to expect any electrical product sold or used here for any purpose to carry a UL listing.

Comment: @bodine NEC 110.2, and just walk the aisles of Home Depot.  If UL listing were optional, you would not find a single UL-listed thing, they would all be crowded out by AliExpress tier crud like the above.